# Retrieving data from the Air Quality Index (AQI) website through the API and only recieving small nr. of stations

Tags: python, dataframe, python-requests, folium

I'm working on a personal project and I'm trying to retrieve air quality data from the https://aqicn.org website using their API.

I've used this code, which I've copied and adapted for the city of Bucharest as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 
import folium 
import requests

# GET data from AQI website through the API

base_url = "https://api.waqi.info"
path_to_file = "~/path"

# Got token from:- https://aqicn.org/data-platform/token/#/
with open(path_to_file) as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
    key = contents[0]

# (lat, long)-> bottom left, (lat, lon)-> top right
latlngbox = "44.300264,25.920181,44.566991,26.297836" # For Bucharest 
trail_url=f"/map/bounds/?token={key}&latlng={latlngbox}" #

my_data = pd.read_json(base_url + trail_url) # Joined parts of URL
print('columns->', my_data.columns) #2 cols ‘status’ and ‘data’ JSON

### Built a dataframe from the json file 
all_rows = []
for each_row in my_data['data']:
    all_rows.append([each_row['station']['name'],
    each_row['lat'],
    each_row['lon'],
    each_row['aqi']])
df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=['station_name', 'lat', 'lon', 'aqi'])

# Cleaned the DataFrame
df['aqi'] = pd.to_numeric(df.aqi, errors='coerce') # Invalid parsing to NaN
# Remove NaN entries in col
df1 = df.dropna(subset = ['aqi'])
```

Unfortunately it only retrieves 4 stations whereas there are [many more available](https://aqicn.org/city/bucharest) on the actual site. In the [API documentation](https://aqicn.org/api/) the only limitation I saw was for "1,000 (one thousand) requests per second" so why can't I get more of them?

Also, I've tried to modify the lat-long values and managed to get more stations, but they were outside the city I was interested in.

[Here](http://bboxfinder.com/#44.300264,25.920181,44.566991,26.297836) is a view of the actual perimeter I've used in the embedded code.

If you have any suggestions as of how I can solve this issue, I'd be very happy to read your thoughts. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using waqi through aqicn... not exactly a clean API but I found it to work quite well

```
import pandas as pd
url1 = 'https://api.waqi.info'
# Get token from:- https://aqicn.org/data-platform/token/#/
token = 'XXX'
box = '113.805332,22.148942,114.434299,22.561716' # polygon around HongKong via bboxfinder.com
url2=f'/map/bounds/?latlng={box}&token={token}'
my_data = pd.read_json(url1 + url2) 

all_rows = []
for each_row in my_data['data']:
    all_rows.append([each_row['station']['name'],each_row['lat'],each_row['lon'],each_row['aqi']])
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows,columns=['station_name', 'lat', 'lon', 'aqi'])
```

From there its easy to plot

```
df['aqi'] = pd.to_numeric(df.aqi,errors='coerce')
print('with NaN->', df.shape)


df1 = df.dropna(subset = ['aqi'])

df2 = df1[['lat', 'lon', 'aqi']]
init_loc = [22.396428, 114.109497]
max_aqi = int(df1['aqi'].max())
print('max_aqi->', max_aqi)
m = folium.Map(location = init_loc, zoom_start = 5)

heat_aqi = HeatMap(df2, min_opacity = 0.1, max_val = max_aqi,
radius = 60, blur = 20, max_zoom = 2)
m.add_child(heat_aqi)
m
```

Or as such

```
centre_point = [22.396428, 114.109497]
m2 = folium.Map(location = centre_point,tiles = 'Stamen Terrain', zoom_start= 6)
for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    lat = row['lat']
    lon = row['lon']
    station = row['station_name'] + ' AQI=' + str(row['aqi'])
    station_aqi = row['aqi']
    if station_aqi > 300:
        pop_color = 'red'
    elif station_aqi > 200:
        pop_color = 'orange'
    else:
        pop_color = 'green'
        folium.Marker(location= [lat, lon],
        popup = station,
        icon = folium.Icon(color = pop_color)).add_to(m2)
m2
```

checking for stations within HK, returns 19

```
df[df['station_name'].str.contains('HongKong')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've tried to use your proposed solution, but from what I can see we're using the same API to retrieve the data. Also, if you enter the 'box' values into bboxfinder.com you'll see that the delimited area exceeds Hong Kong's border so that's why you get more stations. Thank you again for your response!

Comment: Im not so sure there are more than 4 stations in your defined region. your aqicn link shows 4. If you expand to "43.927572,25.502014,44.813019,27.117004" you see 2 additional stations north and northeast of the city.

Answer (score 0):

In order to streamline the process of data retrieval from the Air Quality Index website through their API and extend coverage across a broader array of stations, a strategic approach to utilizing the API endpoints is key.

This involves not only utilizing the available endpoints effectively but also proactively addressing any potential limitations that the API might present.

It's essential to maintain an awareness of the dynamic nature of APIs, especially the [air quality API](https://www.getambee.com/api/air-quality), which may undergo changes and updates. Regularly revisiting and scrutinizing the [API documentation](https://docs.ambeedata.com/DeveloperTools/?refId=airquality&subRefId=airquality-intro) ensures that you're well-informed about the latest features, updates, and any modifications in the structure or functionality of the API. This practice enables you to tailor your data retrieval strategies for optimal performance and relevancy in accordance with the evolving API ecosystem.

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve data from the Air Quality Index (AQI) website through an API and ensure you receive data for a larger number of stations, you need to properly utilize the API endpoints and handle any limitations that the API might have. Keep in mind that the specific details of the AQI API may change over time, so it's essential to review the API documentation for the latest information. I'll provide a general approach using Python and the `requests` library.

Step 1: API Documentation

First, find the official documentation for the AQI API to understand its endpoints, parameters, and limitations.

Step 2: API Usage

You'll need to send requests to the API to retrieve data. The API may have parameters to specify the number of stations or other filtering options. Use these parameters to get more data. Here's a simplified example:

````
```python
import requests
# Replace with the actual API endpoint and API key
API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.example.com/aqi'
API_KEY = 'your_api_key_here'
# Define parameters for the request
params = {
    'api_key': API_KEY,
    'limit': 100,  # Adjust this limit as needed, it may vary based on the API
}
try:
    response = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, params=params)
    response_data = response.json()
    # Process the data here
    for station in response_data['stations']:
        # Process each station's data
        print(station)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print('Error:', e)
```
````

Step 3: Pagination (if needed)

If the API has pagination for the data, you might need to make multiple requests to retrieve data for a larger number of stations. Check the API documentation for information on how to paginate through the data.

Step 4: Error Handling and Rate Limiting

Always handle errors gracefully and respect any rate limiting imposed by the API. If the API has a rate limit, make sure to comply with it to avoid getting blocked.

Remember to replace `API_ENDPOINT` and `API_KEY` with the actual API details provided by the AQI service you're using.

Additionally, please note that this is a basic example, and the actual implementation may vary depending on the AQI API's specifics and requirements. Make sure to review the API documentation thoroughly.